# Python: How to import package from subdirectory

Tags: python, import, package, directory-structure, project-structure

I have the following project structure:

```
Project/
|-- src/
|   |-- package/
|       |-- __init__.py
|       |-- a.py
|       |-- b.py
|
|-- tests/
    |-- test_a.py
```

My `__init__.py` file looks like this

```py
from .a import some_function
from .b import SOME_CONSTANT
```

But now I want to run the following code in `test_a.py`:

```py
import package

package.some_function()
```

As long as it is located in the `src/` directory, everything works fine, I can access all imports defined in my package. But I want it to be in the `tests/` directory.

When looking at the [flask](https://github.com/pallets/flask) repo I found that thex do it like that. For example, flasks [test_appctx.py](https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/tests/test_appctx.py)
does exactly that:

```py
import flask

flask.do_something()
```

How can I achieve this in my project as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `src/` to the folders where to look for the functions:

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('../src')
```

Comment: I guess something like that would work, but it is really good practics? If I recall correctly I read that you should avoid manipulating `sys.path`. And how does flask handle it then? I didn't see anything like that in their code (might have missed it of course)

Comment: It's definitely not a great practice ^^'

`flask` created a package which they installed with pip. In their `setup.cfg`, they point to the folder where the package is written:
https://github.com/pallets/flask/blob/master/setup.cfg#L38

In a simpler way, you can gather your utilities in a folder (say `src`), create a `Project/setup.py` file and install it with `pip install -e .` from the folder `Project`.
Then you can import the functions from anywhere.

Comment: Okay, thank you! I was thinking somelike that (installing the package) but couldnt find it anywhere in their code, as I'm pretty new to projects like this. That really helped.